# Running Docker Images on Raspberry that were build on Windows

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi3

I want to develop apps on my Windows machine using docker and then ship them onto my raspberry pi 3B+('s and run them within a swarm).

However i fail to do so:

I got some helloWorld set up in python on my Windows mashine:

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
import os
import socket

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>"

    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Running

```
docker build --tag=hello .
docker run -p 4000:80 hello
```

works like a charm and even my pushing and getting it back from my registry (running on a Raspberry) via

```
docker build -t somehostname/hello .
docker push somehostname/hello
//delete local container and image
docker run -p 4000:80 somehostname/hello
```

works fine.

However when i ssh into my raspberry 3B+ and run

```
sudo docker pull somehostname/hello
sudo docker run -p 4000:80 somehostname/hello
```

i get:

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I read about this error and it seems to be a problem with the architecture difference: my windows mashine is using x86-64 while the raspberry 3B+ is using ARM.

However the python image i'm building on is made for both architectures so docker should pull the correct image. Also copying the code on my raspberry, build the image and run the container with the exact same lines of code works fine.

I also read about docker manifest and it being an experimental feature but i dont see how that would help me since everything i use (which is only python i guess) is already multiarch so docker should handle this by itself.

Is there a way to get my app up and running without copying code to my raspberry?

**Update:** Output from raspberry

```
user@somehostname:~ $ sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
registry            2                   c99846f41d25        2 months ago        22.1MB
```

```
user@somehostname:~ $ sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2af9cb1df776        registry:2          "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   2 minutes ago       Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

```
user@somehostname:~ $ sudo docker pull somehostname/hello:latest
latest: Pulling from hello
c5e155d5a1d1: Pull complete
221d80d00ae9: Pull complete
4250b3117dca: Pull complete
3b7ca19181b2: Pull complete
425d7b2a5bcc: Pull complete
dc3049ff3f44: Pull complete
472a6afc6332: Pull complete
5f79c90f8d7c: Pull complete
1051ee813012: Pull complete
38d05a77ad85: Pull complete
fe3cbf1eaf8a: Pull complete
c1e865e5779d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f7b31fff3116ef6621bf96fead8858ceb0768b502b2f3b221ab0f52cfc8039eb
Status: Downloaded newer image for somehostname/hello:latest
```

```
user@somehostname:~ $ sudo docker run -p 4000:80 somehostname/hello
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

```
user@somehostname:~ $ sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
somehostname/hello   latest              d7472edad23e        About an hour ago   938MB
registry            2                   c99846f41d25        2 months ago        22.1M
```

```
user@somehostname:~ $ sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2af9cb1df776        registry:2          "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

Comment: I couldn't entirely follow your outputs, a copy of your `siudo docker images` will definately help to entirely understand the problem. I would try to add the tag `:latest` firstly so that you will run the image using `sudo docker run -p 4000:80 somehostname/hello:latest`

Comment: I added the outputs i get from the process i expect to work. I also added the `:latest` tag but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything you wrote it correct but I'm confident that it's not true that the Python image is cross-architecture and you should find a Python image that runs on the Raspberry Pi device that you're using.

IIRC 3s are different ARM architecture than Zeros too so be careful you get the correct one.

The `exec format errror` you include is a strong indicator of this.

Comment: I added the model which is 3B+, sorry about that. I'm still a beginner on docker so i am not really sure if cross-architecture images work how i think they work but
 1) [the python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) has tags for different architectures and the pull command on the right when swtiching is the same
2) when i run the original code on raspberry it works so it gets the correct container. Also if i get an explecit arm-python-image i cant build it on my windows mashine to push it to the registry :/

Comment: Please try `FROM arm32v7/python` (https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/python)